# Rendered file black, even though Play Rendered Animation is correct

Tags: animation

I downloaded a Blender intro template. I rendered it and it saved. I went to open the file, but the video is all black and only the music is playing. I looked at the Blender Play Rendered Animation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>) and it was fine; with video. Please help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you render the file you must choose the output format and the video codecs. Probably your video player is not supporting the video codec that has been rendered.

[image]